# Need help in merging 2 excel files with different column names using Python. Here we need to merge specific columns not all the columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, xlwings

[image]

There are 2 work books with the data that needs to be merged into 1 single table as seen in the table highlighted in yellow. Note that the column names are different in 2 work books. Only Specific columns need to be combined into single column.

Tried some of the options available on google, but did not work, Still new to python and not aware as to what needs to be done.

Comment: Did you manage to get data from Excel to python?

Comment: Yes, The tables are from 2 different files and I need to create one single file containing the columns highlighted in yellow

Comment: Please paste your code to show what you have already done - how you imported data from Excel and how they are represented in Python

Answer (score 0):

This operation is known as merge.
Refer to the documentation for more details.

1. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html

On how it is used in real life datasets:

2. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-merge-two-csv-files-by-specific-column-using-pandas-in-python/

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'John', 'Bob'], 
                    'b': [3, 3, 1, 0],
                    'c': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'John', 'Bob'],
                    'd': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'John', 'Bob']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'John', 'Bob'], 
                    'f': [3, 3, 1, 0],
                    'g': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'John', 'Bob'],
                    'h': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'John', 'Bob']})
x = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer', on = 'a')
x[['a','b']]
```